# PHP: Include library in files in different directories

Tags: php, path, include

My project tree:

[image]

The library **LibB** is used in both **AJAX** and **fileA**, so I have respectively, in each file:

```
include_once "../Lib/LibB.txt"
include_once "Lib/LibB.txt"
```

The problem is that **LibB** depends on **LibA**, and whether I put an include that works for **AJAX** or that works for **fileA**:

```
 include_once "../LibA.txt"
 include_once "LibA.txt"
```

Is there a code that will work for both files?

Comment: non relative (absolute) paths

Comment: @Dagon I have three domains using these files, absolute path is not  working either.

Comment: are the domains on the same server?

Comment: @Dagon nope, three different servers (neither the country is the same)

Comment: you must use absolute URI from at least 2 of the servers then ?

Comment: @Dagon Not exactly, relative paths have worked fine for all of them. So far.

Comment: so each has there own copy so back to my original approach

Comment: @Dagon I was afraid that would be the only option, because I'm talking about 15 files that are going to have to be changed each time they are sent to servers (4 different versions if we include local) and it is not even me the responsible for sending the versions to servers...=/

Comment: each site has one configuration file, with tit's path in it, use that in the other files

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, I didn't get it. Could your explain more? (PS: I gotta leave for a while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the path starting with the current directory

So from LibB.txt, use

```
include __DIR__ . '../LibA.txt';
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

or, assuming this is a website, you could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` before the file name

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/LibA.txt';
```

Answer (score -1):

call all the libraries in one file and call that file before calling your classes classes

```
ex. new file lib_list_request.txt
file list_classes.txt
file interface.txt
```

Like this, you only need to call every file once.